# Use OUTPUT...INTO with different column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following code fails on `DOC_IDX.DocID` with an error

> invalid object name

I'm trying to insert a new record in DOC which contains a primary key `ID` column, and insert that new `ID` value into `DOC_IDX` like this:

```
INSERT INTO DOC ([Field])
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
INTO DOC_IDX.DocID
SELECT ('Test')
FROM Images
```

The `OUTPUT...INTO` examples show using only the table name `INTO DOC_IDX` and it looks for the same column name, I guess. But I need to put the new ID value in a different named column.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `DOC_IDX`  - another existing table? Then you most probably would need `INTO DOC_IDX(DocID)` for your statement

Comment: Yes, DOC_IDX is another table.  That seems to work.

Comment: The next hurdle is to get it to work with multiple fields. This part fails with Incorrect syntax at the 2nd line's comma: 
 OUTPUT inserted.Id, im.Account
 INTO DOC_IDX([DocId]), DOC_IDX([Account])

Comment: Should be `DOC_IDX(DocId,Account)`